# How to make recyclerview hight same as tallest item when multiline text present?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I am using recyclerview where item can have multiline text.the problem arise when one item has single line text and other has multiple lines of text.one item get bigger than other.

I want item height will be same as talles item.How i can achive this?

[image]

Comment: add `android:lines="2"` in your textview in item layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give fixed height to TextView. Like

```
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

Or you can set fix number of lines of TextView

```
android:lines="2"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you inside your Textview tag in the listItem

```html
android:maxLines="1"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="4"
```

This will help text to scroll if its long engouh for one line